# Android CameraX PreviewView: How to get PreviewView height?

Tags: android, android-camerax

My PreviewView is occupying full width and height of the parent layout, but while starting the camera, I am setting the preview's aspect ratio as **AspectRatio.RATIO_16_9**. Due to this, there is some blank space on the top and bottom of my PreviewView.

My question is: how do I get the bounds of the actual camera feed? I need to overlay some custom views on top, hence I need to know the dimensions of the camera feed.

**Edit:** The scaleType is 'fitCenter'. It is intended. The custom view overlay needs to be displayed on top of the camera feed, ignoring the blank space. The camera feed doesn't need to be full screen. I want it to be 16:9 ratio. My use case includes drawing face bounds for face detection, drawing 3x3 grid lines while capturing the image. So the grid lines need to extend only till the bounds where the camera preview ends, not considering the blank spaces around it.

For example, below is my camera screen. The purple rectangle signifies the PreviewView bounds, and the red rectangle is whose bounds I need.

[image]

Comment: "Due to this, there is some blank space on the top and bottom of my PreviewView" is it because you are using a FIT* ScaleType? e.g. https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/view/PreviewView.ScaleType#FIT_CENTER Are the custom view for covering the blank space? If you provide more details about your specific use case, we might be able to better assist you. CameraX provides tools for coordinate transformations.

Comment: The scaleType is 'fitCenter'. It is intended. The custom view overlay needs to be displayed on top of the camera feed, ignoring the blank space. So only the red rectangle in my example needs to be considered for drawing the overlay. The camera feed doesn't need to be full screen. I want it to be 16:9 ratio.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to calculate it yourself. Given that the aspect ratio of the stream is 16:9, assuming the dimension of the PreviewView is (viewW, viewH) then you can calculate the bounding box like this:

```
if (viewW/viewH >9/16) {
  streamH = viewH
  streamW = viewH/16*9
  left = (viewW - streamW)/2
  top = 0
} else {
  streamW = viewW
  streamH = viewW/9*16
  left = 0
  top = (viewH - streamH)/2
}

rect = (left, top, left + streamW, top + streamH)
```

The code is untested.